# Error loading EntityFramework 4.3.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4.1, ninject

I created an MVC application in C#. I created a new project in my solution called PhoneDomain. The purpose of this is to separate my data and domain layer from the actual problem. I right clicked on the project and went to "Add Library Package Reference" and I attempted to add the EntityFramework package (version 4.3.1). It said "`Operation Failed`" "`This package contains an init.ps1 file and needs to be installed from the Package Manager Console`".

So I opened the Package Manager Console in Visual Studio and typed the following into the console window:
`install-package EntityFramework -project PhoneDomain`

After a couple seconds, it installed the package and said `Successfully added 'EntityFramework 4.3.1' to PhoneDomain`

The problem is, when I run my application, I get the following error message: `Could not load file or assembly 'EntityFramework, Version=4.3.1.0, Culture=neutral' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.`

The reference in the PhoneDomain is definately there and the the `Copy Local` property is set to `True`.

Can anyone tell me what is going on here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check your web.config for assembly references.  There may be a rogue reference in there.

UPDATE:
Also make sure ALL projects have the necessary reference...

Comment: Dave, thanks for the suggestion. I got the issue fixed. Your answer gave me the clue. I was not adding a reference to EntityFramework in my WebUI project. I was only adding it to the Domain project. I am using Ninject for dependency injection, which is probably why I need the reference in my WebUI project. Anyway, once I added the reference, my project worked just fine!